# Talking to a professor about a potential research idea

Tags: research-process, ethics, authorship, interpersonal-issues

I am a Master's student in the US. I am in a course and was discussing an idea with the professor and TA for the course. Both of them seemed pretty excited about the idea and said it can become a paper we submit rather than just a term paper for the course. I later fleshed out the ideas and asked for a meeting with the prof and the TA to talk it over in more detail.

A couple of days later, the TA pulled me aside and recommended I not tell the professor about the details, but rather submit the original idea as the term paper and go find some other professor and talk to them about the expanded idea. The TA claimed that the professor was struggling with his research and was likely to try something fishy if I talk to him.

Is this actually a concern or is the TA incorrect? Would you recommend against further discussion about this with the prof and/or the TA? Does me submitting the paper count as proof, if needed, for authorship? I'm not even sure if I can approach someone else in the department about this because it's pretty well known that this professor is the only expert in this subfield in the department. What would be the recommended course of action? I'm very confused - please advise.

Comment: And, can you trust the TA? Something might be fishy, but it is hard to tell from this.

Comment: @Buffy - I'm not entirely sure, but it seems like the TA has nothing to gain by saying this

Comment: Unless they want to take this and do something with it.

Comment: @Buffy - they're not asking me to stop/not write a paper. In any case, the problem still exists. What would you propose? The issue is the subfield is quite niche and this professor is he only one who specializes in this subfield.

Comment: I don't think we can tell you. If this is in the US, this is a pretty extreme move by the TA

Comment: @uucdh There may be a personal issue between TA and professor that has nothing to do with you, and the TA may have wrong ideas about the professor. Meaning that I wouldn't trust the TA blindly even if I knew that he has said this in good faith to you.

Answer (score 0):

If the work is sufficiently novel, then the best course is to write it up for publication, not just a course paper. And, it is editors and reviewers who have the final say on novelty.

The question of authorship remains, however, and can't be judged from what is here. In some fields, authorship is listed alphabetically and all are generally assumed to be equal contributors to the ideas. In others, it is a really big deal who is listed first.

But the three of you are all potential candidates for authorship.

Since you are in a course under this professor, you might ask whether you can publish the work in lieu of a term paper. The situation is a bit unusual, so, perhaps the outcome can be also.

Comment: Sorry for the question (I'm relatively new to this), but why would the professor or TA have authorship claims? Most of the work was done by me and they simply taught the class (ie. the basics of the subfield) and pointed me to papers that I should cite in the "relevant work" section. I imagine I will need help writing the paper itself, but I don't fully understand why they have a substantial authorship claim

Comment: You described "discussions". I don't know what that entailed. It could be anything. Like I said, I can't judge.

Comment: Sure, but would you recommend against further discussion about this with the prof and/or the TA? Does me submitting the paper count as proof, if needed, for authorship? I'm not even sure if I can approach someone else in the department about this because it's pretty well known that this professor is the only expert in this subfield in the department.

Comment: @uucdh If you need help writing the paper itself, that suggests to me you need a coauthor. Knowing what work to cite and how to contextualize what you've done in what's been done before, and even just recognizing that what you're doing is of interest to others beyond a course are all intellectual contributions toward authorship. Whether that should actually *result* in authorship is a bit trickier. I get the impression that it's more common in math for advisors to provide a lot of authorship-style assistance without being credited as an author than in other areas.

Comment: @BryanKrause I see. Given this, should I talk with the prof and/or the TA about this in more detail? I'm not even sure if I can approach someone else in the department about this because it's pretty well known that this professor is the only expert in this subfield in the department

Answer (score 0):

You can write up the idea and communicate it through email to the prof and the TA so that you have evidence that the idea is yours.